# How to set the focus of a picker to true in xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, focus, picker

I create a picker in code, which I insert in a StackLayout, as you can see below :

```
StackLayout stk = new StackLayout()
{
   Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal
};  

PickerPrep = new Picker()
{
   HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
   WidthRequest = 150
};
PickerPrep.SetBinding(Picker.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("DepotsBox"));
PickerPrep.SetBinding(Picker.SelectedItemProperty, new Binding("SelectedDepotBox", BindingMode.TwoWay));

PickerPrep.SetBinding(Picker.MinimumWidthRequestProperty, new Binding("FontSizeSmall"));
PickerPrep.SetBinding(Picker.FontSizeProperty, new Binding("FontSizeSmall"));

PickerPrep.ItemDisplayBinding = new Binding("Box");
PickerPrep.Behaviors.Add(new Prism.Behaviors.EventToCommandBehavior()
{
   EventName = "SelectedIndexChanged", 
   Command = ChoisirDepotBoxCommand 
});
stk.Children.Add(PickerPrep);
```

At this moment, the property `isFocused` of my PickerPrep is set to false.

But when I want to set the focus to the picker, using the `Focus` method, the property is still set to false.

Did I miss something, It is a good way to do that?

I already try to set a binding on the `isFocused` property, but It is the same way.

Comment: `PickerPrep = new Picker()`, you sure that line is right? It should give you an error.

Comment: Yes, forgot in my message but `PickerPrep` is already defined as a property.

Comment: `PickerPrep.SetBinding(Picker.IsFocusedProperty,new Binding("xxx",BindingMode.TwoWay));` And when you click the picker ,the value of xxx should change to true in event `Focus` .

Comment: Are you trying to set focus for the purpose of Accessibility? And are you facing the same issue for iOS & Android?